# Raspberry Pi Pico W Autostart with Network

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to autostart a pico W program.

I can get it to flash LEDs, but when I add my logic about temp sensor and network, it doesn't autostart anymore.

I save this program to main.py.

The program runs when I hit play with Thonny, just does not autostart.

Ignore the messy code, as it's very much a WIP :)

https://pastebin.com/x39b7PgK

````
import network
import urequests
import machine
import utime
import gc   # Import the garbage collector
 
# Connect to network
wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wlan.active(True)
 
led = machine.Pin("LED", machine.Pin.OUT)
 
# Fill in your network name (SSID) and password here:
ssid = 'SuperHot'
password = '(pass)'
while not wlan.isconnected():
    wlan.connect(ssid, password)
    utime.sleep(2)  # Wait for 2 seconds before retrying
 
url = "http://192.168.4.23:8000/data"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "text/plain"
}
 
LM35 = machine.ADC(0)  #setup analog reading on ADC
Cal_Offset = 5050      #Calibration offset value
                       #Determined from practical testing
 
def Compute_Temp(Avg_A):
    LM35_A = Avg_A + Cal_Offset           #Add Calibration Adjustment
    LM35_V = LM35_A * .00005              #Convert analog reading to volts
    Tmp_C  = round((LM35_V * 100),1)      #Convert volts to temp celcius
    Tmp_F  = round((Tmp_C * 1.8 + 32),1)  #Convert Tmp_C to Tmp_F
    return Tmp_C, Tmp_F                   #Return Temps
 
 
Samples = 0            #Variable holds all samples
Num_Samples = 1        #Counter for num samples collected
while True:
    led.on()
    utime.sleep(.5)
    led.off()
    utime.sleep(.25)
    if Num_Samples <= 10:            #storing a total of 10 samples
        LM35_A = LM35.read_u16()     #Read the ADC port to get sensor data
        Samples = Samples + LM35_A   #Add current reading to sample batch
        Num_Samples += 1             #Increment counter
    else:
        Avg_A = Samples / 10             #Get the average of samples
        Samples = 0                      #Reset Samples variable to zero
        Num_Samples = 1                  #Reset counter to one
        T_c, T_f = Compute_Temp(Avg_A)   #Fetch the temps from the function
        data = "Celcius=" + str(T_c) + "  Fahrenheit=" + str(T_f)
        response = urequests.put(url, data=data, headers=headers)
 
        gc.collect()   # Invoke the garbage collector here
 
    utime.sleep(.1)  #slow the loop down```
````

Comment: When you reboot the Pico while connected to the serial port, what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting to network does not look right for me, this part I would change to following:

```
ssid = 'SuperHot'
password = '(pass)'
wlan.connect(ssid, password)   # try to connect
while not wlan.isconnected():  # and then wait till board connects
    utime.sleep(2)  # Wait for 2 seconds before retrying
```

If this does not solve you question- post log from serial console, maybe yu get some errors